# How do i add a custom color property to the nouislider PCF component's index.ts file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, powerapps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gth88.gif)I want to add a custom color property in the following code and want to change the background color of the slider in the css file. How can i do that. I'm not having any experience with the typescript but I've a requirement to do so. This is the index.ts file's code

```
import {IInputs, IOutputs} from "./generated/ManifestTypes";
import noUiSlider = require("nouislider");

export class RangeSliderControl implements ComponentFramework.StandardControl<IInputs, IOutputs> {
    private _slider: HTMLDivElement;

    private _minValue: number;
    private _maxValue: number;
    private _stepValue: number;
    private _upperValue: number;
    private _lowerValue: number;

    private _context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>;
    private notifyOutputChanged: () => void;
    private _container: HTMLDivElement;

    /**
     * Empty constructor.
     */
    constructor()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Used to initialize the control instance. Controls can kick off remote server calls and other initialization actions here.
     * Data-set values are not initialized here, use updateView.
     * @param context The entire property bag available to control via Context Object; It contains values as set up by the customizer mapped to property names defined in the manifest, as well as utility functions.
     * @param notifyOutputChanged A callback method to alert the framework that the control has new outputs ready to be retrieved asynchronously.
     * @param state A piece of data that persists in one session for a single user. Can be set at any point in a controls life cycle by calling 'setControlState' in the Mode interface.
     * @param container If a control is marked control-type='starndard', it will receive an empty div element within which it can render its content.
     */
    public init(context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>, notifyOutputChanged: () => void, state: ComponentFramework.Dictionary, container:HTMLDivElement)
    {
        this.refreshData = this.refreshData.bind(this);

        this.notifyOutputChanged = notifyOutputChanged;
        this._container = container;

        this._minValue = context.parameters.MinValue.raw || 0;
        this._maxValue = context.parameters.MaxValue.raw || 100;
        this._stepValue = context.parameters.StepValue.raw || 10;
        this._upperValue = context.parameters.UpperValue.raw;
        this._lowerValue = context.parameters.LowerValue.raw;

        let showScale = !!context.parameters.ShowScale.raw;
        let requireStep = !!context.parameters.RequireStep.raw;

        this._slider = document.createElement("div");
        this._slider.id = "slider";

        let wrapperContainer = document.createElement("div");
        wrapperContainer.className = "dwcrm-slider-wrapper";

        wrapperContainer.appendChild(this._slider);

        this._container.appendChild(wrapperContainer);

        let startLower:number = this._lowerValue || this._minValue;
        let startUpper:number = this._upperValue || this._maxValue;

        let sliderOptions = this.getSliderOptions(this._minValue, this._maxValue,
            startLower, startUpper, this._stepValue, showScale, requireStep);

        noUiSlider.create(this._slider, sliderOptions);

        // @ts-ignore
        this._slider.noUiSlider.on('change', this.refreshData);
    }

    private getSliderOptions(min:number,max:number, startLower:number, startUpper:number, 
        step:number, showScale:boolean, requireStep:boolean): noUiSlider.Options{

        let options:noUiSlider.Options = {
            start: [startLower, startUpper],
            range: {
                'min': min,
                'max': max
            },
            connect: true,
            tooltips: true
        };

        if(showScale && step){
            options.pips = {
                mode: 'steps',
                values: [0, 50, 100],
                density: 2,
                stepped: true
            };
        }

        if(requireStep){
            options.range = {
                'min': [min, step],
                'max': max
            }
        }

        return options;
    }

    public refreshData(values:string[], handle:number):void{
        console.log("refreshData");
        let value:string = values[handle];

        if(handle == 0){
            this._lowerValue = parseFloat(value);
        } else {
            this._upperValue = parseFloat(value);
        }
        this.notifyOutputChanged();
    }


    /**
     * Called when any value in the property bag has changed. This includes field values, data-sets, global values such as container height and width, offline status, control metadata values such as label, visible, etc.
     * @param context The entire property bag available to control via Context Object; It contains values as set up by the customizer mapped to names defined in the manifest, as well as utility functions
     */
    public updateView(context: ComponentFramework.Context<IInputs>): void
    {
        let updated:boolean = false;
        this._context = context;
        let newUpper = context.parameters.UpperValue.raw;
        if(this._upperValue != newUpper){
            this._upperValue = newUpper;
            updated = true;
        }

        let newLower = context.parameters.LowerValue.raw;
        if(this._lowerValue != newLower){
            this._lowerValue = newLower;
            updated = true;
        }

        if(updated){
            // @ts-ignore
            this._slider.noUiSlider.set([this._lowerValue, this._upperValue]);
        }
    }

    /** 
     * It is called by the framework prior to a control receiving new data. 
     * @returns an object based on nomenclature defined in manifest, expecting object[s] for property marked as “bound” or “output”
     */
    public getOutputs(): IOutputs
    {
        return { 
            UpperValue: this._upperValue, 
            LowerValue: this._lowerValue 
        };
    }

    /** 
     * Called when the control is to be removed from the DOM tree. Controls should use this call for cleanup.
     * i.e. cancelling any pending remote calls, removing listeners, etc.
     */
    public destroy(): void
    {
        // Add code to cleanup control if necessary
    }
}
```

I don't know how to define a variable and pass that variable to the css background-color and will change the value when the user enters the color code

```
.noUi-connect {
  background: #333F48;
}
```

Comment: If you need to use react, you should use the react version of this library, `nouislider-react` https://www.npmjs.com/package/nouislider-react

Comment: Also, you can't change the contents of an external css file from typescript. You can do `<Nouislider style={{bgColor: color}} />` where `color` is a variable that changes based on user input